# Update a field where 2 fields are equal

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a field (points=1)  when 2 other columns (C1 and C2), in the same row, are equal (or when one is bigger than the other)

so far I tried something similar to this:

```
UPDATE table points=1 WHERE C1=C2;
```

I've been doing  this perfectly when I was comparing against a constant (ie: C1= 1 or C1> 1 ) but when it comes to compare columns, it doesn't work.

Comment: How does it not work?  The query would seem to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the `SET` keyword

```
update mytable
set points=1
where c1 >= c2;
```

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem!

Comment: I can't edit it because the typo is too small, but you're going to want to fix the typo in the "where" clause and you changed the equality operator to ">=".

Comment: @Max, thanks for pointing that out. I think OP also mentioned the less than condition.

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it!  Try:

```
UPDATE table SET points=1 WHERE C1=C2;
```

But if your table is actually named "table" or you run into other strange errors, try:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `points` = 1 WHERE `C1` = `C2`;
```

That escapes the names `table`, `points` and `C1` and `C2` in case they conflict with a MySQL keyword.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the SET